# How to save alsamixer settings?

Tags: sound, multimedia

I asked this on reddit on r/elementaryos but it says there that this is the more appropriate forum for this sort of question:

This is a pretty minor problem, but after I boot -- 32-bit eOS 0.3.2 on a Thinkpad x60s laptop -- the USB audio output is on for only one speaker. Changing balance settings, etc., via System Settings / Sound doesn't do anything.

I can use alsamixer to fix the problem by selecting "USB audio device" and altering the level. Then everything is fine -- correct output from left and right.

However, when I reboot, the settings are wrong again. Based on random info from the internet, I have tried running "sudo alsactl store" (as root also) and commenting-out a line in /etc/pulse/default.pa thus: #load-module module-device-restore.

Neither of these worked. Does anyone have any advice? Thank you!

Comment: if you don't get answer here: http://askubuntu.com/ and http://unix.stackexchange.com/ - this may be ubuntu-specific and possibly more general than that.